# POSTing to controller, how to get id from URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

If I POST a form to a target URL which includes an ID, e.g.

```
/mycontroller/createItemAndAddTo/5
```

How can I get to the Id (`=5`) in the `[HttpPost]` ActionResult subroutine (which takes the model as parameter)

I'd like to leave out the `Id` from the POST data/form, and get it from the URL as it is already present there

In this case the Id is a foreign key, and I would normally include it as a hidden field, but it seems unnecessary as it is included already

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a standard route setup which has the `id` as last token of the url then the default model binder will populate its value automatically:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(int id)
{
    // id = 5 here
}
```

or if your view model has an Id property:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(MyViewModel model)
{
    // model.Id = 5 here
}
```

Comment: It has an ModelId but that is for the primary key. In this case it is a foreign key, how can I get to it if it is only present in the URL?

Comment: @goorj, I don't know what primary and foreign keys you are talking about. There are no such notions in ASP.NET MVC. They are relevant only in your data access layer. In ASP.NET MVC controller actions should always take/pass view models from/to views. View models are classes specifically designed for a given view. So in your case your controller action could take a view model which has a property called Id so that the default model binder does the job of mapping it from the url. Then you will pass this value to your DAL layer which will decide whether it's primary, secondary, third key ...

Comment: Ok, if I understand you correctly, if there is an property named "Id" in the (view)model, then the default binder will take the value from the URL, even though the rest of the properties are mapped from the POST data?